# Prove that a point $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$ has the same homotopy type as $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, homotopy-theory

> Prove that a point $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$ has the same homotopy type as $\mathbb{R^2}$.

If someone could verify my proof that would be great. I just started this learning this material and I want to make sure I understand the detail. Thanks in advance.

***Proof:*** Define function $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R^2}$ such that $f(a,b)=(a,b)$. Define function $g:\mathbb{R^2}\to (a,b)$ such that $g(x,y)=(a,b)$. In order to show that $(a,b)$ has the same homotopy type as $\mathbb{R^2}$, we need to show that $g(f)\sim id_{(a,b)}$ and $f(g)\sim id_{\mathbb{R^2}}$. $g(f)=(a,b)=id_{(a,b)}$.

$f(g(x,y))=f(a,b)=(a,b)$. Define function $H:\mathbb{R}^2\times[0,1]\to \mathbb{R^2}$ such that  $H((x,y),t)=((x-a)t+a,(y-b)t+b)$. Then $H((x,y),0)=(a,b)=f(g),$ and $H((x,y),1)=(x,y)=id_{\mathbb{R}^2}$.

Comment: Modulo some quantifiers, this looks good to me!

Comment: Note that what you're actually proving is that if a convex set has the same homotopy type than a point.

Comment: @Taladris Is it true that if nonempty $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ then $A$ has the same homotopy type as a point as well?

Comment: @Misakov: no, What is true is that a nonempty **convex** subset of ${\mathbb R}^n$ has the same homotopy than a point. A circle, for example, does not have the homotopy of a point (its Poincare group is $\mathbb Z$).

Comment: @Taladris That's pretty bad because I just "proved" a unit circle is homotopy equivalent to a point... What about a circle with a point removed? I'm pretty sure that is true since its one of our homework assignments.

Comment: @Misakov: I think you should check your proof (for the circle). A circle with a point removed is homeomorphic to $\R$ (which is convex) so it has the same homotopy type than a point.

Comment: @Taladris Thank you. I will. Just to clarify, the circle with a point removed is h.e to a point, thus h.e to $\mathbb{R}^2$? Did you mean h.e to $\mathbb{R}^1$?

Comment: @Misakov: $\R$ meant ${\mathbb R}^1$ (the habit of using macros in Latex). Sorry. Both ${\mathbb R}^1$ and ${\mathbb R}^2$ are h.e. to a point, so the circle is h.e. to both of them. And to ${\mathbb R}^n$ for every $n\geqslant 0$.